# Natural Language dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, module, nlp

Does anyone know of a python Natural Language Processing Library or module that I could use to find synonyms (or antonyms, etc ..) of english words ?

Answer (score 3):

NLTK is a very popular Python natural language toolkit.

http://nltk.org/

These links cover using NLTK to find synonyms...

http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn-/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html

http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2009/12/28/experimenting-with-nltk

Answer (score 0):

[Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en) is also pretty powerful, and it has several features like pluralization + singularization, conjugation, parsers, wordnet access (from which you can get synonyms and antonyms), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a wordnet, a lexical database made by Princeton university. Its intuitively organized in synsets, which might serve your purpose (if your still interested :)

You can download a local copy of wordnet and import it into your python code to perform NLP tasks.

Link: https://wordnet.princeton.edu/